# how to live reload before posting in to database laravel ex: cell 1+ cell 2 = cell 3 then post

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

am in an edit page and i want to insert the price then insert in-stock then the total price will be calculated automatically in the total-price cell before posting  can any body help ?

**

> the controller page is

**

> adminController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\User;
use App\Product;

class adminController extends Controller
{

public function users()
  {
      $users=User::all();
      $users=User::paginate(5);
      return view('adminVeiw.user', compact('users'));
  }

  public function products()
      {
          $products=Product::all();
          $products=Product::paginate(5);
          return view('adminVeiw.product', compact('products'));
      }


/////////////////////////////////Users//////////////////////////////////////////////

public function addUser(Request $request){
if($request->isMethod('post')){

$this->validate($request,[
 'id' => 'required | max:5 |unique:users' ,
///  'price' => 'required |min:2 |max:8'
]);

   $users = new User();
   $users->id=$request->input('id');
   $users->name=$request->input('name');
   $users->email=$request->input('email');
   $users->password=$request->input('password');
   $users->phone=$request->input('phone');
   $users->save();
}

           return view('adminVeiw.userAdd');


}



public function EditUser(Request $request,$id){

if($request->isMethod('post')){
$users= User::find($id);
$users->id=$request->input('id');
$users->name=$request->input('name');
$users->email=$request->input('email');
$users->password=$request->input('password');
$users->phone=$request->input('phone');
       $users->save();
       return redirect("users");

}else{
$users=User::find($id);
$arr=Array('users'=>$users);
return view('adminVeiw.userEdit',$arr);
}

}


///////////////////////////////Product////////////////////////////////////////////////


public function AddProduct(Request $request){
if($request->isMethod('post')){

$this->validate($request,[
 'id' => 'required | max:5 |unique:products' ,
///  'price' => 'required |min:2 |max:8'
]);

   $products = new Product();
   $products->id=$request->input('id');
   $products->name=$request->input('name');
   $products->barcode=$request->input('barcode');
   $products->price=$request->input('price');
   $products->instock=$request->input('instock');
   $products->tax=$request->input('tax');
   $products->taxval=$request->input('taxval');
   $products->discount=$request->input('discount');
   $products->discountval=$request->input('discountval');
   $products->description=$request->input('description');
   $products->totalPrice=$request->input('totalPrice');
   $products->file=$request->input('file');
   $products->save();
}

           return view('adminVeiw.productAdd');


}



public function EditProduct(Request $request,$id){

if($request->isMethod('post')){
$products= Product::find($id);
$products->id=$request->input('id');
$products->name=$request->input('name');
$products->barcode=$request->input('barcode');
$products->price=$request->input('price');
$products->instock=$request->input('instock');
$products->tax=$request->input('tax');
$products->taxval=$request->input('taxval');
$products->discount=$request->input('discount');
 $products->discountval=$request->input('discountval');
$products->description=$request->input('description');
$products->totalPrice=$request->input('totalPrice') ;
$products->file=$request->input('file');
$products->save();
   return redirect("products");
  //  return view('adminVeiw.productEdit');





}else{
$products=Product::find($id);
$arr=Array('products'=>$products);
return view('adminVeiw.productEdit',$arr);
}

}

///////////////////////////////////////////search function
public function searchproduct(Request $request)
{
  $products = $request->get('products');
  $products = DB::table('products')->where('name', 'like', '%'.$products.'%')->paginate(5);
    return view('adminVeiw.product', ['products' => $products]);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


}

?>
```

> **productEdit.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="container">
<div class="card "  style="width: 50rem;">
  <div class="card-header ">
    <h1> EDIT PRODUCT </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">

<form action="/productEdit/{{$products->id}}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
 <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('id') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
 <h5>ID</h5>
<input type="lable" name="id" value="{{$products->id}}" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" />
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('barcode') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<h5>BARCODE</h5>
 <input type="text" name="barcode" value="{{$products->barcode}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Barcode" />
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('name') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<h5>NAME</h5>
 <input type="text" name="name" value="{{$products->name}}" class="form-control" placeholder="name" />
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('description') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<h5>DESCRIPTION</h5>
<input type="text" name="description" value="{{$products->description}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" />
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('file') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<h5>FILE</h5>
<input type="text" name="file" value="{{$products->file}}" class="form-control" placeholder="IMG/URL" />
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('instock') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<h5>IN STOCK</h5>
<input type="text" name="instock" value="{{$products->instock}}" class="form-control" placeholder="In Stock" />
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('price') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<h5>PRICE</h5>
<input type="text" name="price" value="{{$products->price}}" class="form-control" placeholder="PRICE" />
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('discount') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<h5>DISCOUNT</h5>
<input type="text" name="discount" value="{{$products->discount}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Discount" />
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('discountval') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<h5>DISCOUNT VALUE</h5>
<input type="text" name="discountval" value="{{$products->discountval}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Discount Value" />
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('tax') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<h5>TAXES</h5>
<input type="text" name="tax" value="{{$products->tax}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Taxes" />
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('taxval') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<h5>TAXES VALUE</h5>
<input type="text" name="taxval" value="{{$products->taxval}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Taxes Value" />
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('totalPrice') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<h5>TOTAL PRICE</h5>
<input type="text" name="totalPrice" value=" {{$products->totalPrice = $products->price + $products->instock }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Price" />
</div>
</br>


<a  class="btn btn-warning" href="/products"> Returne without Saving  </a>


<input class="btn btn-success"  type="submit" value="Confirm changes">

</form>


  </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection('content')
```

> and this the routs **web.php**

```
Route::get('/products', 'adminController@products');
Route::get('productAdd/{id}',function ($id){
$products=Product::find($id);
$products->delete();
return redirect("products");
});
Route::post('productAdd',"adminController@AddProduct");
Route::get('productAdd',"adminController@AddProduct");

Route::get('productEdit/{id}',"adminController@EditProduct");
Route::post('productEdit/{id}',"adminController@EditProduct");
```

**any ideas even from beginners is allowed**

Comment: What you have tried so far .? and getting any error .?

Comment: i played around with the <form action="/productEdit/{{$products->id}}" method="POST">           it didn't work

Comment: also     Route::get('productEdit/{id}',"adminController@EditProduct");
Route::post('productEdit/{id}',"adminController@EditProduct");     that didn't work to

Comment: and  the  return redirect("products"); which made the app did't know where to go

Comment: means you want to edit some resource .?

Comment: the main idea is that the data in the product.blade.php   will have the right value     foreach($products as $c)
{{$c->totalPrice = $c->price + $c->instock }}  but when i checked the db it was not stored

Comment: yes but i want to make totalprice change automatic on changing the price or any other cell that is related to the total  before the posting

Comment: so you should ask that in question rather then hole code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221930/discussion-between-ahmed-and-kamlesh-paul).

Answer (score 0):

> a way to get through : is to create a new controller that do the same
> job of `product.blade.php`  but with a button (save-confirm-etc)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h3> <p style="text-align:center;">Products</p> </h3>
                </div>
           </br>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <h4>Veiw as a seller</h4>
                </div>

                <!---the form ------------------------->

                <div class="card-body">
      <a  class="btn  btn-outline-secondary btn-lg btn-block" href="/home">Go Home   </a>
      </div>

                <div class="card-body">
<a  class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg btn-block" href="/productAdd">Add new product   </a>
</div>

              <!---search icon------------------------------>
<form  action="/search" method="get">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="search" name="products" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-prepend">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>

                 <table class="table table-striped">
                   <thead>
                     <tr>
                       <th scope="col">ID</th>
                       <th scope="col">Barcode</th>
                       <th scope="col">Name</th>
                       <th scope="col">Description</th>
                       <th scope="col">Image</th>
                       <th scope="col">In Stock</th>
                       <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
                       <th scope="col">Unit Discount</th>
                       <th scope="col">Unit Discount Value</th>
                       <th scope="col">Tax</th>
                       <th scope="col">Tax Value</th>
                       <th scope="col">Total Price</th>
                       <th scope="col">Save</th>
                       <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                       <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                     </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                     @foreach($products as $c)
                     <tr>
                      <th scope="row">{{$c->id}}</th>
                      <td> {{$c->barcode}}</td>
                      <td> {{$c->name}}</td>
                      <td> {{$c->description}}</td>
                      <td><img src="{{$c->file}}" alt="" style="width: 7rem;"></td>
                      <td> {{$c->instock}}</td>
                      <td>{{$c->price}}</td>
                      <td> {{$c->discount}}</td>
                      <td> {{$c->discountval}}</td>
                      <td> {{$c->tax}}</td>
                      <td> {{$c->taxval}}</td>
                      <td>  {{$c->totalPrice = $c->price + $c->instock }} </td>

<td>
                  <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="productSave/{{$c->id}}">save</a>
                  </td>

                      <td>
                      <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="productEdit/{{$c->id}}">EDIT</a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="productAdd/{{$c->id}}">Delete</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                      @endforeach

                  </tbody>
                </table>
<div class="paginations col-lg-12">
  {!! $products->render() !!}
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

that will do the same thing that the `edit.blade.php` will do  but now it will check the values before fetching  then the submit this time will return doing nothing but you got the idea

```
>  @extends('layouts.app')
>     @section('content')
> 
>     <div class="container ">
>     <div class="card "  style="width: 50rem;">
>       <div class="card-header ">
>       <h1>Are you shure you want to save ?</h1>
>       </div>
>       <div class="card-body ">
> 
>     <form action="/productSave/{{$products->id}}" method="POST">
>     {{ csrf_field() }}
> 
> 
>         <a  class="btn btn-warning" href="/productSaved"> NO  </a>
> 
>         <input class="btn btn-success"  type="submit" value="yes" >
>      <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('id') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
> 
> 
>      <h5>ID</h5>
>     <input type="lable" name="id" value="{{$products->id}}" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" />
>     </div>
>     </br>
>     <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('barcode') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
>     <h5>BARCODE</h5>
>      <input type="text" name="barcode" value="{{$products->barcode}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Barcode" />
>     </div>
>     </br>
>     <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('name') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
>     <h5>NAME</h5>
>      <input type="text" name="name" value="{{$products->name}}" class="form-control" placeholder="name" />
>     </div>
>     </br>
>     <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('description') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
>     <h5>DESCRIPTION</h5>
>     <input type="text" name="description" value="{{$products->description}}" class="form-control"
> placeholder="Description" />
>     </div>
>     </br>
>     <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('file') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
>     <h5>FILE</h5>
>     <input type="text" name="file" value="{{$products->file}}" class="form-control" placeholder="IMG/URL" />
>     </div>
>     </br>
>     <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('instock') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
>     <h5>IN STOCK</h5>
>     <input type="text" name="instock" value="{{$products->instock}}" class="form-control" placeholder="In Stock" />
>     </div>
>     </br>
>     <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('price') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
>     <h5>PRICE</h5>
>     <input type="text" name="price" value="{{$products->price}}" class="form-control" placeholder="PRICE" />
>     </div>
>     </br>
>     <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('discount') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
>     <h5>DISCOUNT</h5>
>     <input type="text" name="discount" value="{{$products->discount}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Discount" />
>     </div>
>     </br>
>     <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('discountval') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
>     <h5>DISCOUNT VALUE</h5>
>     <input type="text" name="discountval" value="{{$products->discountval}}" class="form-control"
> placeholder="Discount Value" />
>     </div>
>     </br>
>     <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('tax') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
>     <h5>TAXES</h5>
>     <input type="text" name="tax" value="{{$products->tax}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Taxes" />
>     </div>
>     </br>
>     <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('taxval') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
>     <h5>TAXES VALUE</h5>
>     <input type="text" name="taxval" value="{{$products->taxval}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Taxes Value" />
>     </div>
>     </br>
>     <div class="form-group{{$errors -> has('totalPrice') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
>     <h5>TOTAL PRICE</h5>
>     <input type="text" name="totalPrice" value=" {{$products->totalPrice = $products->price + $products->instock }}"
> class="form-control" placeholder="Total Price" /> </form>
>     </div>
>     </br> </div> </div>
> 
> </div>
> 
> 
> @endsection('content')
```

> by the way the new controller will be something like `savedController.php` :

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\User;
use App\Product;


class savedController extends Controller
{
  public function products()
      {
          $products=Product::all();
          $products=Product::paginate(5);
          return view('adminVeiw.productSaved', compact('products'));
      }


/////////////////////////////////save editing ///////////////////////////


public function EditProduct(Request $request,$id){

if($request->isMethod('post')){
$products= Product::find($id);
$products->id=$request->input('id');
$products->name=$request->input('name');
$products->barcode=$request->input('barcode');
$products->price=$request->input('price');
$products->instock=$request->input('instock');
$products->tax=$request->input('tax');
$products->taxval=$request->input('taxval');
$products->discount=$request->input('discount');
 $products->discountval=$request->input('discountval');
$products->description=$request->input('description');
$products->totalPrice=$request->input('totalPrice') ;
$products->file=$request->input('file');
$products->save();
        return redirect("productSaved");


}else{
$products=Product::find($id);
$arr=Array('products'=>$products);
return view('adminVeiw.productSave',$arr);
}

}
}
```